# Обновление конкретного элемента списка в RecyclerView через DiffUtil

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

У меня в приложении имеется экран с отображением Bluetooth устройств. Если посмотреть на скриншот, то там видно что у каждого элемента RecyclerView есть текстовое поле с текстом **"Connect"**. Идея такая что когда мы нажимаем на это текстовое поле, то должно произойти подключение. И Если подключение происходит, то элемент списка должен приобрести вид, как это видно на третьей позиции списка.

Проблема собственно в  том, что у меня не получается сделать это динамически. То есть когда я нажал на **Connect**, то элемент списка у меня никаким образом не обновился. Он обновится в том случае если я перейду на какой то другой экран а затем обратно и только можно видеть что список обновился.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В своем адаптере я использовал **DiffUtil**, но он корректно только обновляет элементы списка, когда я например делаю переименование устройства или например когда удаляю устройство -- тут он отрабатывает нормально. С полезными нагрузками через метод `getChangePayload(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Any?` у меня не получилось что либо сделать. Он просто на просто не отрабатывает или я что то делаю не так.

**Как у меня происходит обратная связь до списка?**

При нажатии на Connect отправляется запрос до сервиса, который управляет Bluetooth соединениями. Сервис в свою очередь если соединение прошло успешно возвращает ответ об успешном подключении, этот ответ у меня так же записывается в модель данных в поле isConnected: Boolean. Тоже самое происходит при получении значения батареи. Далее в адаптере в **DiffUtil** проверяю, отличаются ли старые и новые данные.

**Код адаптера с DiffUtil**

```
class DeviceListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var mData: MutableList<DeviceModel> = ArrayList()
    private var itemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    private lateinit var binding: ItemDeviceListBinding

    private val viewBinderHelper = ViewBinderHelper()

    fun addData(deviceModels: List<DeviceModel>) {
        Log.e("Adapter", "addData: ADAPTER DATA")
        for (device in deviceModels) {
            Log.d(
                "Adapter",
                "    ${device.macAddress}, ${device.batteryLevel}, ${device.isConnected}"
            )
        }
        val diffUtilCallback = DiffUtilCallback(mData, deviceModels)
        val diffUtilResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtilCallback)
        mData = ArrayList(deviceModels)
        diffUtilResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = listener
    }

    fun removeOnItemClickListener() {
        itemClickListener = null
    }

    /*fun setConnectionState(position: Int, macAddress: String, isConnected: Boolean) {
        notifyItemChanged(position, ConnectionState(macAddress, isConnected))
    }

    fun setBatteryLevel(position: Int, macAddress: String, batteryLevel: Int) {
        notifyItemChanged(position, BatteryState(macAddress, batteryLevel))
    }

    data class ConnectionState(
        val macAddress: String,
        val isConnected: Boolean
    )

    data class BatteryState(
        val macAddress: String,
        val batteryValue: Int
    )*/

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemDeviceListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(deviceModel: DeviceModel) {
            binding.tvNameDevice.text = deviceModel.name
            binding.tvAddressDevice.text =
                if (deviceModel.groupName.isNotEmpty()) deviceModel.groupName
                else "Ungrouped"

            binding.ivBattery.setBatteryLevel(deviceModel.batteryLevel)

            if (deviceModel.isConnected) {
                binding.tvConnect.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.viewColor.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.ivBattery.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.ivBtnPower.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                binding.tvConnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.viewColor.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.ivBattery.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                binding.ivBtnPower.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createCombinedPayload(payloads: List<Change>): Change {
        assert(payloads.isNotEmpty())
        val firstChange = payloads.first()
        val lastChange = payloads.last()

        return Change(firstChange.oldData, lastChange.newData)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ItemDeviceListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val deviceModel = mData[position]
        viewBinderHelper.setOpenOnlyOne(true)
        viewBinderHelper.bind(holder.itemView.swipelayout, deviceModel.macAddress)
        viewBinderHelper.closeLayout(deviceModel.macAddress)

        binding.tvConnect.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener?.onItemActionConnectClick(
                deviceModel, position
            )
        }
        binding.tvAddToGroup.setOnClickListener {
            viewBinderHelper.closeLayout(deviceModel.macAddress)
            itemClickListener?.onAddSaberToGroup(deviceModel)
        }
        binding.tvRename.setOnClickListener {
            viewBinderHelper.closeLayout(deviceModel.macAddress)
            itemClickListener?.onRenameSaber(deviceModel)
        }
        binding.tvRemove.setOnClickListener {
            viewBinderHelper.closeLayout(deviceModel.macAddress)
            itemClickListener?.onRemoveSaber(deviceModel)
        }
        binding.ivBtnPower.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener?.onItemActionPowerClick(deviceModel, position)
        }
        binding.containerItemSaber.setOnClickListener {
            itemClickListener?.onItemClick(deviceModel)
        }

        holder.bind(deviceModel)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            val combinedPayload = createCombinedPayload(payloads as List<Change>)
            val oldData = combinedPayload.oldData
            val newData = combinedPayload.newData
            
            if (oldData.isConnected != newData.isConnected) { 
                if (newData.isConnected) {
                    binding.tvConnect.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    binding.viewColor.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.ivBattery.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.ivBtnPower.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    binding.tvConnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.viewColor.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    binding.ivBattery.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    binding.ivBtnPower.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            } 
        } else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = mData.size

    private data class Change(
        val oldData: DeviceModel,
        val newData: DeviceModel
    )

    inner class DiffUtilCallback(
        private val oldList: List<DeviceModel>,
        private val newList: List<DeviceModel>
    ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

        override fun getOldListSize(): Int = oldList.size

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int = newList.size

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldList[oldItemPosition].macAddress == newList[newItemPosition].macAddress &&
                    oldList[oldItemPosition].name == newList[newItemPosition].name &&
                    oldList[oldItemPosition].groupName == newList[newItemPosition].groupName
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            /*oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]*/
            return oldList[oldItemPosition].batteryLevel == newList[newItemPosition].batteryLevel &&
                    oldList[oldItemPosition].isConnected == newList[newItemPosition].isConnected
        }

        override fun getChangePayload(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Any? {
            val oldItem = oldList[oldItemPosition]
            val newItem = newList[newItemPosition]
            return Change(
                oldItem,
                newItem
            )
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(deviceModel: DeviceModel)
        fun onItemActionConnectClick(deviceModel: DeviceModel, position: Int)
        fun onItemActionPowerClick(deviceModel: DeviceModel, position: Int)
        fun onAddSaberToGroup(deviceModel: DeviceModel)
        fun onRemoveSaber(deviceModel: DeviceModel)
        fun onRenameSaber(deviceModel: DeviceModel)
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Или можно как то сделать по другому, например через `notifyItemChanged(position, payload)`. Но тогда возникает проблема с позицией. Как ее получить по элементу, если адаптер не предоставляет никаких методов для ее получения. Если бы обновление списка проходило одномоментно например по нажатию чего либо и там в  адаптере сразу вызвать `notifyItemChanged` тогда да -- во view holdere можно получить эту самую позицию и обновить. Но вот когда обновление надо сделать как то из вне, то тут я просто захожу в тупик.

Подскажите как правильно нужно сделать?

Comment: Весь код не смотрел, глубоко в проблему не вникал, однако вот это в глаза бросилось: `mData = ArrayList(deviceModels)`. Попробуйте вместо этого список очистить и заново наполнить: `mData.clear() mData.addAll(deviceModels)`

Comment: ЮрийСПб, Пробовал. Я разные варианты пробовал. Изначально было так как вы предложили, но это не помогло. Путем экспериментов у меня это вылилось в то что вы видите.

Comment: Вы же же назначаете листенеры на нажатие кнопок, А вызываете функцию fun setOnItemClickListener за пределами адаптера ,верно? А значит в колбеках получаете позицию. Когда получили изменение состояния, просто изменить соответствующий элемент массива, который передаете адаптеру, потом вызовите adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

Comment: А вообще, я кажется нашел причину. В функции bind у вьюхолдера в самом низу вызываем binding.executePendingBindings()